# Algebraic Proof exam question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given that $5(x + k) = 4x + 20$ and that $x$ is positive. Show that $k < 4$ .

What I did

$5k + 5x = 4x + 20$

$x = 20 - 5k$

But I don't know what to do next.

Thank You and help is appreciated.

Comment: Like, an old exam or one you're taking right now?

Comment: This question is from an Old exam.

Answer (score 4):

> What I did
>
> $5k + 5x = 4x + 20$
>
> $x = 20 - 5k$

Now use the fact that $x$ is positive, so:
$$ x > 0 \implies 20-5k > 0 \iff \ldots$$
Can you solve for $k$?

Comment: 20 - 5k > 0 so k = 4

Comment: Where does the equality come from? You have $20-5k>0$ so $20 > 5k$ so, after division by $5$, you get...

Comment: 4 > k is with the inequality

Comment: And that's correct...

Comment: Thank You for helping me !